# C++, GoogleTests и возможная утечка макетного объекта

Tags: c++, mock, shared-ptr

Я бы хотел разобраться в одной странной ситуации.

Ситуация следующая: есть `GoogleTests`, есть предупреждения о возможной утечке макетного объекта. В результате анализа кода, я нашел странную конструкцию.

Если конструкцию максимально упростить, то она будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class Object
{
    // ...
};

class MockObject : public Object
{
    // ...
};

shared_ptr<Object> getObject()
{
    return make_shared<MockObject>();
}

TEST(A, B)
{
    shared_ptr<Object> object = getObject();

    // Корректно ли это?
    MockObject *mock_object = dynamic_cast<MockObject*>(object.get());
    // ...

    // GoogleTests предупреждает о возможной утечке mock_object.
}
```

Классический подход, используемый в текстах, - создание макетного объекта путем наследования. Макетный объект используется вместо базового. Естественно, базовый объект является полиморфным, имеет виртуальный деструктор, и с ним вроде бы все в порядке.

Но.

У меня есть большие сомнение, относительно:

1. Законности возврата `shared_ptr<MockObject>` вместо `shared_ptr<Object>`;
2. Компланарности `shared_ptr<MockObject>` и `shared_ptr<Object>`;
3. Законности `dynamic_cast`; Возможно, здесь есть нарушение правил `strict aliasing`?

Comment: *"предупреждения о возможной утечке макетного объекта"* - стоит привести текст этого предупреждения

Answer (score 3):

Ну, вы выдрали сырой указатель из умного. Теперь вы - ССЗБ, потому что если умный указатель досчитает до нуля, он грохнет объект, а ваш сырой указатель даст UB при первом же разыменовывании.

Ответьте для себя на вопрос - почему именно shared_ptr, а не unique_ptr?

С алиасингом у вас проблемы в данном конкретном примере не возникнут, это вам не int* a= &float;

Comment: Это не мой код. Я понимаю, что он "необычный". Сырой указатель используется корректно - только тогда, когда реальный объект еще существует. Я подумал, что преобразование shared_ptr вида Derived->Base->Derived может создать проблемы.

Comment: ...преобразование просто не откомпилируется.

Comment: @gbg, для данной ситуации какая разница  использован  shared_ptr или  unique_ptr?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Ликвидация неуместных накладных расходов.

Comment: Согласен с неуместными накладными расходами, но  в коде я вообше не вижу  никаких проблем.  Думаю предупреждение исчезнет после явного удаления через обычный указатель

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Тогда программа начнет валиться при удалении внутри shared_ptr

Comment: @gbg, соглашусь с вами, но а если сбросить право владения через reset()?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan тогда абсолютно весь смысл засовывания сюда умного указателя теряется - можно сразу из объекта возвращать сырой. 
Умный указатель сюда намеренно (и неправильно, нужно было unique_ptr) засунули для автоматического delete.